# How can I detect subdomains by analyzing a URL?

Tags: python, string, urlparse

I've a couple of websites that are subdomains (e.g., `Wordpress, Altervista, Blogpress`,...).

I'm currently using url parse for splitting URLs into their elements. However it seems that does not allow to distinguish subdomains, but only tld.

Alternatively, I'd use a vocabulary to include all the subdomain suffixes and, based on that, assign `1` or `0`. But since I don't know all the blogs, I'm wondering if there is a way to make automatically the detection.

For example, I was thinking of looking at the dots, but many websites can have a dot in between not being subdomains, so this approach is not good.

Comment: What do you mean by "blog"? Did you mean a subdomain?

Comment: yes, something like : `https://artgateblog.altervista.org` or `https://www.this-is-an-example.blogspot.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this library should do the trick https://pypi.org/project/tld/.

Here's an example:

```
from tld import get_tld
url = "https://artgateblog.altervista.org/"
res = get_tld(url, as_object=True)
blogname, blog_domain = res.domain, res
print(blogname, blog_domain)
```

Out:

```
artgateblog altervista.org
```

EDIT after comments:

For domains that don't include protocol, I think you need to add it with something like the below:

```
from tld import get_tld
urls = ["12story.altervista.org", "fantasy_story.blogspot.com"]
for url in urls:
    res = get_tld(url, as_object=True, fix_protocol=True)
    blogname, blog_domain = res.domain, res
```

Comment: thanks osint_alex. I think get_tld can't be applied in case the protocol is missing. I am getting the message `TldBadUrl: Is not a valid URL` for some URLs

Comment: Can you give an example of those urls?

Comment: An example is `12story.altervista.org` or `fantasy_story.blogspot.com` . Both protocol and www are missing. I've tried with  `try: 
            res = get_tld(url, as_object=True)
        except: 
            res = get_tld(url, fix_protocol=True)` but it gives the error TldDomainNotFound: Domain 12story didn't match any existing TLD name!

Comment: @osint_alex You don't have to do that. There is a `fix_protol` argument that automatically fixes the URL for you. FYI `print(get_tld("12story.altervista.org", fix_protocol=True))` works fine for me.